# SQL TRIGGER TO VALIDATE EMPTY FIELDS

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have an external program that uses SQL Server, the software is written already so m trying to create a trigger that validates that all the fields are filled when the status changes to 3 but its only validating the first one even if I insert something in it,  it keeps validating yet I have entered information there

my code is like this

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[VALIDATE] ON [dbo].[InvNum]
FOR UPDATE
AS
if (( select orderstatusid from inserted) = 3) AND ((select [DocType] from inserted) = 4)
BEGIN

        If((SELECT ucIDSOrd01Product from inserted) ='')
        begin
            RAISERROR ('Please enter Product Description', 12,1)
        end

        if((SELECT ucIDSOrd01LoadingPoint from inserted) = '')
        begin
            RAISERROR ('Please enter the Loading Point', 12,1)
        end

        If((SELECT ulIDSOrd02Units from inserted) ='')
        begin
            RAISERROR ('Please enter a Unit', 12,1)
        end
END
```

Comment: Why don't you use a check constraint?  Btw: your trigger will fail if more than one row is inserted

Comment: All those fields are for one row...

Comment: An even better reason to use a check constraint. And `inserted` can contain more than one row!

Comment: If i use a check constraint it will check all the time yet i only want it to fire when the status is 3 and Doctype is 4..

Comment: You can include the condition `orderstatusid = 3` in the check constraint

Comment: Will use the check contsraint changed the code its still validating the first line only, even if i put the description it still says please enter product description.

Answer (score 2):

As @a_horse_with_no_name has already mentioned, triggers fire once per UPDATE, not once per row, so you have to code accordingly. You also need to ROLLBACK to cancel the update, RAISERROR alone is not sufficient. Your trigger should probably look something like this;

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[VALIDATE] ON [dbo].[InvNum] FOR UPDATE AS
if (exists (select 1 from inserted where orderstatusid = 3 and [DocType] = 4))
BEGIN
    If (exists (SELECT 1 from inserted where isnull(ucIDSOrd01Product, '') = '' and orderstatusid = 3 and [DocType] = 4))
    begin
        RAISERROR ('Please enter Product Description', 12,1)
        rollback
        return
    end

    if ( exists (SELECT 1 from inserted where isnull(ucIDSOrd01LoadingPoint, '') = '' and orderstatusid = 3 and [DocType] = 4))
    begin
        RAISERROR ('Please enter the Loading Point', 12,1)
        rollback
        return
    end

    If (exists (SELECT 1 from inserted where isnull(ulIDSOrd02Units, '') = '' and orderstatusid = 3 and [DocType] = 4))
    begin
        RAISERROR ('Please enter a Unit', 12,1)
        rollback
        return
    end
END
```

However, as @a_horse_with_no_name has also mentioned, a check constraint might be a better choice, it depends on your overall system design.

```
alter table [dbo].[VALIDATE] add constraint CK_ucIDSOrd01Product check (isnull(ucIDSOrd01Product, '') <> '' or orderstatusid <> 3 or [DocType] <> 4)
alter table [dbo].[VALIDATE] add constraint CK_ucIDSOrd01LoadingPoint check (isnull(ucIDSOrd01LoadingPoint, '') <> '' or orderstatusid <> 3 or [DocType] <> 4)
alter table [dbo].[VALIDATE] add constraint CK_ulIDSOrd02Units check (isnull(ulIDSOrd02Units, '') <> '' or orderstatusid <> 3 or [DocType] <> 4)
```

Comment: delete row before `BEGIN`

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri I was trying to keep the code close to the OPs original code, it's not how I would write it myself.